# Queries on Repository Layer in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, poco

I am building MVC 5 application using Razor.

My application is layered as below:

1. UI Layer: Comprising of Model, View and Controller.
2. Data Access Layer: Connection and Stored Procedure classes
3. Business Layer (Service Layer)
4. Repository

I referred to [Contosso Sample Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). There it is using DAL to store Repository. But I am creating a separate layer.

I want to know:

1. Whether to keep Repository as a separate layer or in DAL?
2. UI layer Model holds View Models. Where does other models go? Do they reside in Repository Layer? Are these called POCO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually, the Repository is the method of accessing the data and is therefore just an implementation technique of the DAL. I'd combine them both as the DAL.
2. In terms of other models, I assume you mean the classes that correspond with your data items. These should also live in the DAL/Repository layer. They are referred to as POCOs as they don't contain any implementation, simply a list of properties (plain old CLR object).

Comment: Can I keep a separate Repository Layer for better abstraction?

Comment: @RKh Abstraction of what though? I'm all for abstraction, but these two are essentially the same and no doubt you'll quiz yourself each time you add something as to which of these it should fall under.

Comment: I don't want to mix with DAL because DAL only contains connection and calls to Stored Procedures. I therefore want to keep Repo separately.

Comment: @RKh If you'd prefer that separation, then go for it :). These architectural "guidelines" are nothing more than a guide. You'll encounter deviations depending on different requirements, so feel free to keep them separately. Might be a good idea to name them a bit better though. DAL is fine, but what else will be in Repo other than the POCOs?

Comment: I plan to put interfaces and CRUD methods in Repo.

Comment: @RKh Fair enough, that makes sense.